# Getting not aligned value error in statsmodel

Tags: python, machine-learning, statsmodels

I am using `statsmodel` for robust regression and getting the following error:

```
not aligned: 9 (dim 1) != 258095 (dim 0).
```

I think this is because of the x_train and y_train shape. X_train and y_train are NumPy arrays. Here is my code

```
# Input
print(X1)
print(y1)  
X_train, X_test, y_train, y_test = train_test_split(X1, y1, test_size=0.15)
print(X_train.shape)
print(y_train.shape)
rlm_model = sm.RLM(X_train,y_train, M=sm.robust.norms.HuberT())
rlm_results = rlm_model.fit()

# output
X1=[[  36.299999    4.8       321.       ... 1341.         22.
 0. ]
y1=[1.700012 1.600006 1.399994 ... 1.899994 0.899994 1.199997]
x_train shape=(258095, 9)
y_train shape=(258095,)

#value error on rlm_model.fit()
```

Comment: Could you show a few examples of the values on variables `x1` and 'y1`? Because I guess one of them is a class variable and the model only accepts numerical values.

Comment: I have updated the code to show this. xicocaio

Comment: Still, you should provide a minimal reproducible example. There is not enough information to get the same errors and help you. Please provide clearer functional examples.

Answer (score 1):

You have your variables in the wrong order. It should be

```
rlm_model = sm.RLM(y_train, X_train, M=sm.robust.norms.HuberT())
rlm_results = rlm_model.fit()
```

See [the help for RLM](https://www.statsmodels.org/stable/generated/statsmodels.robust.robust_linear_model.RLM.html).  `endog` is what most people call `y` and `exog` is what most would call `x`.